# Consulta JPQL - SQL

Tags: java, sql, banco-de-dados, jpa, jpql

boa noite.

Eu tenho uma bean, que tem um método init(). Um dos objetivos dessa init é trazer o ciclo que foi aberto de acordo com o curso daquele usuário, ou seja, Caso não tenha nenhum ciclo ou processo de avaliação envolvido com o curso daquele usuário logado não será mostrado nenhum simulado para ele responder.

O problema é que tá dando pau na minha Query:

```
private List<Ciclo> ciclosCurso = new ArrayList<Ciclo>();

private void init(){
  this.ciclosCurso = CicloDAO.buscaCicloPorCursoDoUsuario(codigoUsuario);
}
```

CICLODAO:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Ciclo> buscaCicloPorCursoDoUsuario(Long codigo) {
        return  manager
                .createQuery("select c from Ciclo c JOIN curso_ciclo a WHERE CODIGO_CURSO = ?1")
                .setParameter(1, codigo).getResultList();
    }
```

Essa tabela curso_ciclo é um relacionamento entre Curso e Ciclo de muitos para muitos, ou seja, **@ManyToMany**

Da um erro na Query,

**ERROR:  Path expected for join!
Out 31, 2015 12:17:29 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR:  Path expected for join!**

Comment: Falta a cláusula `ON` do [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentando escrever uma query sql em um JPQL, na verdade, a navegação em uma JPQL funciona como a navegação na sua classe mesmo, nada de tabelas envolvidas, sendo assim, para fazer sua query o correto seria.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT ciclo from Curso curso JOIN FETCH curso.ciclos ciclo WHERE curso.codigo = ?1"
```

Esta query pode não funcionar de cara, pois estou apenas supondo os nomes das variáveis em seu bean, mas basta substituir.

A lógica é simples, você está buscando os ciclos presentes no bean de curso onde o curso tenha o código igual a determinado valor.

Uma outra maneira de escrever a mesma query seria pelo lado inverso, sem FETCH:

```
"SELECT ciclo from Ciclo ciclo WHERE ciclo.curso.codigo = ?1"
```

Nesta query, o join é implícito pelo JPA, uma vez que o ciclo tem um curso já atribuido.

Eu particularmente prefiro a última, mais simples, mais clara, maior desempenho, mas você pode escolher a que melhor lhe convir dependendo do seu mapeamento